# how to select a data from another data using a key

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have two data, 1.txt and 2.txt, I am trying to get those that are in 1.txt from the 2.txt

1.txt is

```
P13674
Q7Z4N8
O14683
Q9UHX1
```

and 2.txt is the following

```
>sp|Q96A73|P33MX_HUMAN Putative monooxygenase p33MONOX OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=KIAA1191 PE=1 SV=1
RNDDDDTSVCLGTRQCSWFAGCTNRTWNSSAVPLIGLPNTQDYKWVDRNSGLTWSGNDTCLYSCQNQTKGLLYQLFRNLFCSYGLTEAHGKWRCADASITNDKGHDGHRTPTWWLTGSNLTLSVNNSGLFFLCGNGVYKGFPPKWSGRCGLGYLVPSLTRYLTLNASQITNLRSFIHKVTPHR
>sp|P13674|P4HA1_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA1 PE=1 SV=2
VECCPNCRGTGMQIRIHQIGPGMVQQIQSVCMECQGHGERISPKDRCKSCNGRKIVREKKILEVHIDKGMKDGQKITFHGEGDQEPGLEPGDIIIVLDQKDHAVFTRRGEDLFMCMDIQLVEALCGFQKPISTLDNRTIVITSHPGQIVKHGDIKCVLNEGMPIYRRPYEKGRLIIEFKVNFPENGFLSPDKLSLLEKLLPERKEVEE
>sp|Q7Z4N8|P4HA3_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-3 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA3 PE=1 SV=1
MTEQMTLRGTLKGHNGWVTQIATTPQFPDMILSASRDKTIIMWKLTRDETNYGIPQRALRGHSHFVSDVVISSDGQFALSGSWDGTLRLWDLTTGTTTRRFVGHTKDVLSVAFSSDNRQIVSGSRDKTIKLWNTLGVCKYTVQDESHSEWVSCVRFSPNSSNPIIVSCGWDKLVKVWNLANCKLK
>sp|P04637|P53_HUMAN Cellular tumor antigen p53 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53 PE=1 SV=4
IQVVSRCRLRHTEVLPAEEENDSLGADGTHGAGAMESAAGVLIKLFCVHTKALQDVQIRFQPQL
>sp|P10144|GRAB_HUMAN Granzyme B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=GZMB PE=1 SV=2
MQPILLLLAFLLLPRADAGEIIGGHEAKPHSRPYMAYLMIWDQKSLKRCGGFLIRDDFVLTAAHCWGSSINVTLGAHNIKEQEPTQQFIPVKRPIPHPAYNPKNFSNDIMLLQLERKAKRTRAVQPLRLPSNKAQVKPGQTCSVAGWGQTAPLGKHSHTLQEVKMTVQEDRKCES
>sp|Q9UHX1|PUF60_HUMAN Poly(U)-binding-splicing factor PUF60 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=PUF60 PE=1 SV=1
MGKDYYQTLGLARGASDEEIKRAYRRQALRYHPDKNKEPGAEEKFKEIAEAYDVLSDPRKREIFDRYGEEGLKGSGPSGGSGGGANGTSFSYTFHGDPHAMFAEFFGGRNPFDTFFGQRNGEEGMDIDDPFSGFPMGMGGFTNVNFGRSRSAQEPARKKQDPPVTHDLRVSLEEIYSGCTKKMKISHK
>sp|Q06416|P5F1B_HUMAN Putative POU domain, class 5, transcription factor 1B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=POU5F1B PE=5 SV=2
IVVKGHSTCLSEGALSPDGTVLATASHDGYVKFWQIYIEGQDEPRCLHEWKPHDGRPLSCLLFCDNHKKQDPDVPFWRFLITGADQNRELKMWCTVSWTCLQTIRFSPDIFSSVSVPPSLKVCLDLSAEYLILSDVQRKVLYVMELLQNQEEGHACFSSISEFLLTHPVLSFGIQVVSRCRLRHTEVLPAEEENDSLGADGTHGAGAMESAAGVLIKLFCVHTKALQDVQIRFQPQLNPDVVAPLPTHTAHEDFTFGESRPELGSEGLGSAAHGSQPDLRRIVELPAPADFLSLSSETKPKLMTPDAFMTPSASLQQITASPSSSSSGSSSSSSSSSSSLTAVSAMSSTSAVDPSLTRPPEELTLSPKLQLDGSLTMSSSGSLQASPRGLLPGLLPAPADKLTPKGPGQVPTATSALSLELQEVEP
>sp|O14683|P5I11_HUMAN Tumor protein p53-inducible protein 11 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53I11 PE=1 SV=2
MIHNYMEHLERTKLHQLSGSDQLESTAHSRIRKERPISLGIFPLPAGDGLLTPDAQKGGETPGSEQWKFQELSQPRSHTSLKVSNSPEPQKAVEQEDELSDVSQGGSKATTPASTANSDVATIPTDTPLKEENEGFVKVTDAPNKSEISKHIEVQVAQETRNVSTGSAENEEKSEVQAIIESTPELDMDKDLSGYKGSSTPTKGIENKAFDRNTESLFEELSSAGSGLIGDVDEGADLLGMGREVENLILENTQLLETKNALNIVKNDLIAKVDELTCEKDVLQGELEAVKQAKLKLEEKNRELEEELRKARAEAEDARQKAKDDDDSDIPTAQRKRFTRVEMARVLMERNQYKERLMELQEAVRWTEMIRASRENPAMQEKKRSSIWQFFSRLFSSSSNTTKKPEPPVNLKYNAPTSHVTPSVK
```

the output will look like this

```
 >sp|P13674|P4HA1_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA1 PE=1 SV=2
VECCPNCRGTGMQIRIHQIGPGMVQQIQSVCMECQGHGERISPKDRCKSCNGRKIVREKKILEVHIDKGMKDGQKITFHGEGDQEPGLEPGDIIIVLDQKDHAVFTRRGEDLFMCMDIQLVEALCGFQKPISTLDNRTIVITSHPGQIVKHGDIKCVLNEGMPIYRRPYEKGRLIIEFKVNFPENGFLSPDKLSLLEKLLPERKEVEE
>sp|Q7Z4N8|P4HA3_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-3 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA3 PE=1 SV=1
MTEQMTLRGTLKGHNGWVTQIATTPQFPDMILSASRDKTIIMWKLTRDETNYGIPQRALRGHSHFVSDVVISSDGQFALSGSWDGTLRLWDLTTGTTTRRFVGHTKDVLSVAFSSDNRQIVSGSRDKTIKLWNTLGVCKYTVQDESHSEWVSCVRFSPNSSNPIIVSCGWDKLVKVWNLANCKLK
>sp|Q9UHX1|PUF60_HUMAN Poly(U)-binding-splicing factor PUF60 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=PUF60 PE=1 SV=1
MGKDYYQTLGLARGASDEEIKRAYRRQALRYHPDKNKEPGAEEKFKEIAEAYDVLSDPRKREIFDRYGEEGLKGSGPSGGSGGGANGTSFSYTFHGDPHAMFAEFFGGRNPFDTFFGQRNGEEGMDIDDPFSGFPMGMGGFTNVNFGRSRSAQEPARKKQDPPVTHDLRVSLEEIYSGCTKKMKISHK
>sp|O14683|P5I11_HUMAN Tumor protein p53-inducible protein 11 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53I11 PE=1 SV=2
MIHNYMEHLERTKLHQLSGSDQLESTAHSRIRKERPISLGIFPLPAGDGLLTPDAQKGGETPGSEQWKFQELSQPRSHTSLKVSNSPEPQKAVEQEDELSDVSQGGSKATTPASTANSDVATIPTDTPLKEENEGFVKVTDAPNKSEISKHIEVQVAQETRNVSTGSAENEEKSEVQAIIESTPELDMDKDLSGYKGSSTPTKGIENKAFDRNTESLFEELSSAGSGLIGDVDEGADLLGMGREVENLILENTQLLETKNALNIVKNDLIAKVDELTCEKDVLQGELEAVKQAKLKLEEKNRELEEELRKARAEAEDARQKAKDDDDSDIPTAQRKRFTRVEMARVLMERNQYKERLMELQEAVRWTEMIRASRENPAMQEKKRSSIWQFFSRLFSSSSNTTKKPEPPVNLKYNAPTSHVTPSVK
```

I was trying to do it with bash like this

```
cat 1.txt | grep -A 2.txt | sed -n -e '1,/>/ {/>/ !' > myout.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F '|' 'FNR == NR { id[$1]; next } /^>/ && ($2 in id) { print; getline; print }' 1.txt 2.txt
```

The `awk` program, as a free-standing `awk` script, with comments:

```
BEGIN {
    # Set input field separator to a pipe character.
    FS = "|"
}

FNR == NR {
    # This line comes from the first file.
    # Add the protein ID to the id array as a key,
    # then immediately continue with the next cycle.

    id[$1]
    next
}

# The rest will only ever be executed while reading the second file.

/^>/ && ($2 in id) {
    # This line is a Fasta header line (starts with >),
    # and the ID found in the second field is an index in the id array.

    print;   # output the current line (Fasta header)
    getline; # get the next line
    print;   # output that line too (Fasta sequence)
}
```

This assumes that all protein sequences always use only a single line (i.e., there is never a multi-line sequence in your Fasta file).

The script reads first the file with protein IDs in it, and remembers these.  Then it reads from the Fasta file and outputs the headers and the sequence associated with the protein IDs read from the first file.

Comment: what if there is multi-line sequences ?

Comment: @Learner Then this script would only give you the first line of sequence.  Please update your question with more specific info.  The sequences that you posted were all on single lines.

Comment: is it possible to also know which one of them are retrieved and which one not ? , by the way I liked your answer because of great explanation

Comment: @Learner Please update your question with more specific info and requirements.

Answer (score 4):

If your sequences are really only in one line you can simply use

```
$ grep -f 1.txt 2.txt
```

You are working with fasta files. So I strongly recommend to work with existing program that are specialized for that, e.g. [seqkit](https://bioinf.shenwei.me/seqkit/usage)

```
$ seqkit grep -r -f 1.txt 2.txt
```

The standard output of seqkit will break the sequences after 60 characters to a new line. If you like to have them still in one line, pass the result to `seqkit seq` like this

```
$ seqkit grep -r -f 1.txt 2.txt|seqkit seq -w0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
# grep -A1 -F -f  1.txt 2.txt | grep -v '\-\-'


>sp|P13674|P4HA1_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA1 PE=1 SV=2
VECCPNCRGTGMQIRIHQIGPGMVQQIQSVCMECQGHGERISPKDRCKSCNGRKIVREKKILEVHIDKGMKDGQKITFHGEGDQEPGLEPGDIIIVLDQKDHAVFTRRGEDLFMCMDIQLVEALCGFQKPISTLDNRTIVITSHPGQIVKHGDIKCVLNEGMPIYRRPYEKGRLIIEFKVNFPENGFLSPDKLSLLEKLLPERKEVEE
>sp|Q7Z4N8|P4HA3_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-3 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA3 PE=1 SV=1
MTEQMTLRGTLKGHNGWVTQIATTPQFPDMILSASRDKTIIMWKLTRDETNYGIPQRALRGHSHFVSDVVISSDGQFALSGSWDGTLRLWDLTTGTTTRRFVGHTKDVLSVAFSSDNRQIVSGSRDKTIKLWNTLGVCKYTVQDESHSEWVSCVRFSPNSSNPIIVSCGWDKLVKVWNLANCKLK
>sp|Q9UHX1|PUF60_HUMAN Poly(U)-binding-splicing factor PUF60 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=PUF60 PE=1 SV=1
MGKDYYQTLGLARGASDEEIKRAYRRQALRYHPDKNKEPGAEEKFKEIAEAYDVLSDPRKREIFDRYGEEGLKGSGPSGGSGGGANGTSFSYTFHGDPHAMFAEFFGGRNPFDTFFGQRNGEEGMDIDDPFSGFPMGMGGFTNVNFGRSRSAQEPARKKQDPPVTHDLRVSLEEIYSGCTKKMKISHK
>sp|O14683|P5I11_HUMAN Tumor protein p53-inducible protein 11 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53I11 PE=1 SV=2
MIHNYMEHLERTKLHQLSGSDQLESTAHSRIRKERPISLGIFPLPAGDGLLTPDAQKGGETPGSEQWKFQELSQPRSHTSLKVSNSPEPQKAVEQEDELSDVSQGGSKATTPASTANSDVATIPTDTPLKEENEGFVKVTDAPNKSEISKHIEVQVAQETRNVSTGSAENEEKSEVQAIIESTPELDMDKDLSGYKGSSTPTKGIENKAFDRNTESLFEELSSAGSGLIGDVDEGADLLGMGREVENLILENTQLLETKNALNIVKNDLIAKVDELTCEKDVLQGELEAVKQAKLKLEEKNRELEEELRKARAEAEDARQKAKDDDDSDIPTAQRKRFTRVEMARVLMERNQYKERLMELQEAVRWTEMIRASRENPAMQEKKRSSIWQFFSRLFSSSSNTTKKPEPPVNLKYNAPTSHVTPSVK
```

- `-F` Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings
- `-f` Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.

Comment: I liked it already, I did not know ne can use -F and -f !!!

Comment: @Learner Note that this also only ever gives you the first line of sequence.

Answer (score 2):

From your example I assume your file `2.txt` contains 3 columns separated by `|` and only the second column can contain the keys from `1.txt`.

```
fgrep -f <(sed 's/.*/|&|/`' 1.txt) 2.txt
```

The `sed` command adds leading and trailing `|`, the output of the substitution `<(...)` is used as the pattern file for fgrep.

Comment: I liked your answer

Answer (score 2):

## Using Perl5

This will process multi-line sequences.

### `process.pl`

Takes keys on STDIN, and data files in args.

```
use v5.10;
my %keys;
while (<STDIN>) {
  chomp;
  $keys{$_} = undef;
}
while ( <<>> ) {                  # read from args
  state $s = 0;                   # State; $s==1 for print
  if (/^>/) {                     # In header
    my $id = [split '\|',3]->[1]; #   get id
    $s = exists $keys{$id};       #   check for id in keys, set $s
  }
  print if $s;                    # check $s and print
}
```

### Invocation

```
cat keys.txt | perl process.pl data.txt
```

Comment: I liked your answer

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [join(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join) program is for:

```
$ join -t\| -1 1 -2 2 -o '2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4' <(sort 1.txt) <(sort -t\| -k2 2.txt)
>sp|O14683|P5I11_HUMAN Tumor protein p53-inducible protein 11 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53I11 PE=1 SV=2
>sp|P13674|P4HA1_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA1 PE=1 SV=2
>sp|Q7Z4N8|P4HA3_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-3 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA3 PE=1 SV=1
>sp|Q9UHX1|PUF60_HUMAN Poly(U)-binding-splicing factor PUF60 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=PUF60 PE=1 SV=1
```

This command expects the inputs to be sorted into the same order, which is why I'm using a subcommand to do that first. If you have multiple such queries and/or you're not using bash as a shell, it is probably best to sort the files first, then join them:

```
sort 1.txt >1.sorted
sort -t\| -k2 2.txt >2.sorted
join -t\| -1 1 -2 2 -o '2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4' 1.sorted 2.sorted
```

or, more generic:

```
# delimiter
d=\|
# left column
lc=1
# right column
rc=2
# output format
fmt=2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4

sort -t$d -k$lc 1.txt >1.sorted
sort -t$d -k$rc 2.txt >2.sorted
join -t$d -1 $lc -2 $rc -o $fmt 1.sorted 2.sorted
```

Comment: Where did the actual sequence data go in the result?  Note that the result needs to be on the format specified in the question.